# Convert any length signed hexadecimal number to signed decimal number (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hex, decimal

***Question***

When faced with signed hexadecimal numbers of unknown length, how can one use Excel formulas to easily convert those hexadecimal numbers to decimal numbers?

***Example***

```
Hex
---
00
FF
FE
FD
0A
0B
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this deeply nested [formula](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/767831-signed-hex-numbers.html):

```
=HEX2DEC(N)-IF(ISERR(FIND(LEFT(IF(ISEVEN(LEN(N)),N,CONCAT(0,N))),"01234567")),16^LEN(IF(ISEVEN(LEN(N)),N,CONCAT(0,N))),0)
```

where `N` is a cell containing hexadecimal data.

This formula becomes more readable when expanded:

```
=HEX2DEC(N) -
 /* check if sign bit is present in leftmost nibble, padding to an even number of digits if necessary */
 IF( ISERR( FIND( LEFT( IF( ISEVEN(LEN(N))
                          , N
                          , CONCAT(0,N)
                          )
                      )
                , "01234567"
                )
          )
   /* offset if sign bit is present */
   , 16^LEN( IF( ISEVEN(LEN(N))
               , N
               , CONCAT(0,N)
               )
            )
   /* do not offset if sign bit is absent */
   , 0
   )
```

and may be read as "First, convert the hexadecimal value to an unsigned decimal value.  Then offset the unsigned decimal value if the leftmost nibble of the data contains a sign bit; else do not offset."

***Example Conversion***

```
Hex  | Dec
-----|----
00   |   0
FF   |  -1
FE   |  -2
FD   |  -3
0A   |  10
0B   |  11
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, you may appreciate this expansion to the original answer.  The original formula did not handle data with an odd number of nibbles, whereas this formula does.

Answer (score 5):

Let the `A1` cell contain a 1 byte hexadecimal string of any case.

To get the 2's complement decimal value of this string, use the following:

```
=HEX2DEC(A1) - IF(HEX2DEC(A1) > 127, 256, 0)
```

For an arbitrary length of bytes, use the following:

```
=HEX2DEC(A1) - IF(HEX2DEC(A1) > 2^(4*LEN(A1))/2 - 1, 2^(4*LEN(A1)), 0)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response @Daniel - I suspect that would work well for signed 8-bit integers but would fail for wider datatype bitwidths.

Comment: Oh, sorry all your examples were for 1 byte numbers, I'll add the general case to my answer.

Comment: I did not use any of the formulas here, but this answer makes sense and is easy to memorize. I would thus prefer it over the first answer by @EricSchnipke which looks way less intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use MOD function, but it needs addition and substraction of half the max value. For an 8-bit hex number:

```
=MOD(HEX2DEC(A1) + 2^7, 2^8) - 2^7
```

Of course it can be made a generic formula based on length:

```
=MOD(HEX2DEC(A1) + 2^(4*LEN(A1)-1), 2^(4*LEN(A1))) - 2^(4*LEN(A1)-1)
```

But sometimes input value has lost leading zeroes or maybe you are using hex values of an arbitrary length (I usually have to decode registers from microcontrollers where maybe a 16-bit register has been used for 3 signed values). I prefer keeping bit length in a separate column:

```
=MOD(HEX2DEC(A1) + 2^(B1-1), 2^(B1)) - 2^(B1-1)
```

***Example conversion***

```
HEX  | bit # | Dec
-----|-------|------
   0 |    8  |    0
  FF |    8  |   -1
  FF |   16  |  255
FFFE |   16  |   -2
 2FF |   10  | -257
```